# Spring MVC - how to return different JSON responses based on query parameters?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I am implementing a REST api using Spring MVC. The requirement is:

1. `/transactions` returns an array of transactions.
2. `/transactions?groupByCategory` returns transactions grouped by categories.

For example request #1 returns:

```
[
    { "id": 1, "category": "auto", "amount": 100 },
    { "id": 2, "category": "misc", "amount": 200 },
    { "id": 3, "category": "auto", "amount": 300 }
]
```

whereas request #2 groups this result by category and returns the sum of each category:

```
[
    { "category": "auto", "amount": 400 },
    { "category": "misc", "amount": 200 }
]
```

Obviously the return value from these requests is of different types. How do I do this in Spring MVC? So far I have:

```
@RequestMapping("/transactions")
public List<Transaction> getTransactions(
        @RequestParam(value="groupByCategory", required=false) String groupByCategory
        ) {

    ...
}
```

But this fixes the return type to `List<Transaction>`. How do I accommodate the second type: `List<TransactionSummaryByCategory>`?

**Edit**: I found one solution, i.e. to specify the return type as `Object`. That seems to work and the response is serialized correctly based on the object type. However, I wonder if this is a best practice!

```
public Object getTransactions(...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How about returning only List.

Comment: That's better than what I have! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply provide two methods in your controller. First one returning `List<Transaction>` mapped using

```
@RequestMapping("/transactions")
```

and the second one returning `List<TransactionSummaryByCategory>` and mapped using

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transactions", params = "groupByCategory")
```

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet. This is the most elegant answer. I did not know that Spring MVC allows you to narrow requests by parameters!

Answer (score 1):

You can return a generic List.

```
public List<?> getTransactions() 
{
}
```

Based on the request params you can populate the list with the appropriate objects